# retrofit not send or receive anything

Tags: android, retrofit

I would like to send a post request to my url `RestFul` api :

my url : https://api.vavkhan.com/users/

my gradle :

```
    // Retrofit
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'

// JSON Parsing
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'

    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
```

my class's :

[image]

```
public interface APIService
{
    @POST("/posts")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<MainActivity> savePost(@Field("email") String email,
                                  @Field("firstname") String firstname,
                                  @Field("password") String password,
                                  @Field("lastname") String lastname);

}
```

---

```
public class RetrofitClient
{

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl) {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class ApiUtils
{

    private ApiUtils() {}

    public static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.vavkhan.com/users/";

    public static APIService getAPIService() {

        return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(APIService.class);
    }

}
```

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private APIService mAPIService;
    //REST API
    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("firstname")
    @Expose
    private String firstname;
    @SerializedName("lastname")
    @Expose
    private String lastname;
    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;
    @SerializedName("cell_phone")
    @Expose
    private Object cellPhone;
    @SerializedName("profile_picture")
    @Expose
    private Object profilePicture;
    @SerializedName("credit")
    @Expose
    private Integer credit;

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Object getCellPhone() {
        return cellPhone;
    }

    public void setCellPhone(Object cellPhone) {
        this.cellPhone = cellPhone;
    }

    public Object getProfilePicture() {
        return profilePicture;
    }

    public void setProfilePicture(Object profilePicture) {
        this.profilePicture = profilePicture;
    }

    public Integer getCredit() {
        return credit;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setCredit(Integer credit) {
        this.credit = credit;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"1 + + + + + + + + + + ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return "MainActivity{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstname='" + firstname + '\'' +
                ", lastname='" + lastname + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", cellPhone=" + cellPhone +
                ", profilePicture=" + profilePicture +
                ", credit=" + credit +
                '}';

    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAPIService = ApiUtils.getAPIService();

        sendPost("TTTTTTTTTest@gmail.com", "test","test","test");
    }



    public void sendPost(String email, String firstname,String lastname,String password) {
        mAPIService.savePost(email, firstname,lastname, password).enqueue(new Callback<MainActivity>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MainActivity> call, Response<MainActivity> response) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"1 + + + + + + + + + + ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    showResponse(response.body().toString());
                    Log.e("TEst", "post submitted to API." + response.body().toString());

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"1"+response.body().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MainActivity> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("TAG", "Unable to submit post to API.");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"2 error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void showResponse(String response) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"3"+response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("taaag",response);
    }



}
```

In my console or my screen not show anything !

Answer (score 2):

Change  @POST("/posts") to  @POST("posts") and try.

Answer (score 0):

Since '/' is already included at the end of your BASE_URL, you don't need to include it in `@POST("/posts")`. Just change it to `@POST("posts")`.